# 02 ford f150 v6 manual clutch problems

Tags: ford, transmission, f-150, clutch-hydraulics

i have a 02 ford f150v6 manual. i was pulling my camper no problem. i stopped on a hill. burnt the clutch and had to back up. went into gear no problem and pulled her up the hill to flat ground and shut her off. when i tried to start it up again couldnt engage clutch. wouldnt turn over cause of neutral switch. clutch was hard and wouldnt go down. pushed down a little harder and kinda felt like pumping brakes. was getting harder and farther up. i got mad and pushed too hard then it went completely limp. i broke the slave  cylinder. truck started in gear and pulled camper, evan shifts just hard.      my question is could i have got air in my clutch line when i burnt it or did i screw up my whole clutch? after i burnt the clutch i left truck running, put it in reverse with clutch working, backed up, used clutch to put it in gear, it stalled so i started it but clutch felt different, backed up more to flatter land and put her in first, clutch still felt different, kinda softer at beginning than tighter. made it up the hill and stopped her on flat ground, when i first tried i could turn it over but didnt start, then i couldnt turn it over with clutch all the way down.  after that clutch wouldnt go down, kinda felt like pumping brakes.. could it have been an air pocket i forced outta my slave cylinder hose? it drives just fine, but odviously doesnt have a clutch. and to start you have to have it off, put it in gear, put clutch rown evan though it doesnt work. then start it from starter. then she drives and shifts but to stop you have to shut it off cause when she stops she wont go back in gear.. i know i write a book for a question but i dont wanna replace slave cylinder and have same problem when she goes back together

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: 1-A manual with a towing package parked on an incline simply adds a higher 
 load on a clutch  compared to starting on level ground.
2-All manuals use a master and slave unit; the master/clutch pedal pumps  pressure and transfers pressure to the slave to operate the clutch. Master or slave can be blown with hydraulic oil leaving evidence on the ground.